# request, response JSON format for retrieve KB Article for the query string in servicenow using RET API

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

We are currently working on a POC, One of the scenario is to retrieve the KB article from the servicenow based on the query serach(short_description) and display the solutiopn steps in a web page.

We would like to know request, response JSON format/schema for the below sample REST api

Ex: https://myinstance.service-now.com/api/now/table/kb_knowledge?sysparm_query=short_descriptionLIKE VPN Access

Note: particularly we would like to know, how the KB article is embeded in the response JSON property.

Regards,
Kishore Ilaka

Answer (score 0):

Go to

https://yourInstance.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2F$restapi.do

Select kb_knowledge as tableName und hit Submit.